# includegraphics: one single picture not found

Tags: pdftex, external-files, includegraphics, folders

I include about 100 pics in a LaTeX document and **only one** of these pics is not found:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File
pic_053_001_A_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test.pdf not found
```

**All pics** are in the *same* folder—the same folder as the `.tex` document—, the names are very similar, and I use the *same* command **for all** pics `\includegraphics[width=\picturewidth]{<picture name>}`. For example, `\includegraphics[width=\picturewidth]{pic_053_001_A_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test}`

I thought it was a problem with the file format, that something was corrupted in this concrete pdf file, but if I include the whole path at that sole pic, then everything compiles fine

```
  \includegraphics[width=\picturewidth]{/home/myuser/folder1/folder2/pic_053_001_A_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test}
```

Moreover, if I just change the rename the picture in the folder, for example, I add an underscore at the end`pic_053_001_A_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test_.pdf`, then the `includegraphics` command works (!)

```
\includegraphics[width=\picturewidth]{pic_053_001_A_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test_}
```

Even if I change the name of the picture in the `\includegraphics` command, to other picture in the folder, e.g., `pic_053_001_E_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test`, it works.

```
  \includegraphics[width=\picturewidth]{pic_053_001_E_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test}
```

I am at my wits' end. Of course, at the moment, I will use a quick fix (writing the whole path for this sole file), but that it is not the optimal solution. I appreciate any help, any possible hint on what is failing here.

**Extra Info:**
Here a link to the list of files in that folder. https://docdro.id/atr200p
The main LaTeX file is `data_table_py_diss.tex`

PS: I have no other picture with exactly the same name in the folder.

Comment: (1) which OS are you on? (2) can we see a listing of the files in that folder.

Comment: @daleif I am on Linux (Xubuntu 16.04.). I have added a link to the files in that folder :)

Comment: Can you zip the entire folder and send it to me, email address is just my username plus @gmail.com please also list which latex installation you are using.

Comment: Wow, I am touched for your readiness to help, Mange tak!. I have some concerns about my privacy to send you the whole data. I have to ponder trying to make a light version of it (without personal stuff) to send. I will let you know.

Comment: all files in your folder have two b: `_bb_` but above you are using three.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer nice catch

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for trying to find the error, and, actually you found **a** mistake, congrats!. However, that is not the cause of the compiling error: the names I use here are dummies for the sake of privacy; I made a mistake copying bb into the chat—which I have corrected—, but the error remains ;-(

Comment: sorry but if you don't tell the truth about the file names it is nonsense to ask here. If latex can't find a file, it is normally due to a typo, and such typos can not be identified through fake data.

Comment: I just changed the names of the files consistently, therefore, the question makes perfect sense. I hope you understand that I want to keep the real names hidden. As you see from the usage of the full path, which gives **no error**, it seems quite improbable it is a typo. Surely it is a very strange bug or error. Thanks again for taking a look at this complicated problem. :)

Comment: You gave no proof that the absolute path is actually the same path of the other pictures. From your data it is quite possible that the picture is in `folder2` while all the others are in `folder20`. And as you have no idea what it is happening, claiming that the data you didn't provide don't contain a clue is quite daring. If you don't want to show the real file names: copy and rename your files so that you can run a test and show a log-file with the faked file names.

Comment: Good idea. I'll consider this option: to make a WME for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! A very strange bug.
The problem was that, without apparent reason, there was a copy of my file `pic_053_001_A_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test.pdf` at the *log files* folder. When I **deleted the copy** everything run smooth.

I explain the configuration that caused this error:

- I run `pdflatex` with the option `-output-directory=/home/user/latex-log-files`
- In TexStudio I set *Build > Build Options > Log File* option to this path `/home/user/latex-log-files`
- I had used `\input` to include the parent file in my *main* file and, in this *parent* file, I used `\subimport` to include the file with the faulty command `\includegraphics`
- I had a file named `pic_053_001_A_ccc_SS_bb_TT21_test.pdf` at the path `/home/user/latex-log-files`

Consequently, if **inexplicably** a .pdf file in `includegraphics` gives the `! Package pdftex.def Error: file not found`. It might be that a copy of it is at the log files folder. check it!

**Note:** to find copies of a file in Linux use the  `locate`